# Make ruby object respond to arbitrary messages?

Tags: ruby

Is there equivalent of python `__getattr__` in ruby (for finding methods at least)?

```
class X(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return lambda x: print("Calling " + name + ": " + x)

x = X()
x.some_method("some args")
```

So it could be something like:

```
class X
    # .. ??? ..
    def default_action(method_name, x)
        puts "Calling {method_name}: {x}"
    end
end

x = X.new()
x.some_method("some args")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. If an object does not respond to a message, Ruby will send a `method_missing` message with the message selector and the arguments to the receiver:

```
class X
  def method_missing(selector, *args, &blk)
    puts "The message was #{selector.inspect}."
    puts "The arguments were #{args.map(&:inspect).join(', ')}."
    puts "And there was #{blk ? 'a' : 'no'} block."
    super
  end
end

x = X.new
x.some_method('some args', :some_other_args, 42)
# The message was :some_method.
# The arguments were "some args", :some_other_args, 42.
# And there was no block.
# NoMethodError: undefined method `some_method'

x.some_other_method do end
# The message was :some_other_method.
# The arguments were .
# And there was a block.
# NoMethodError: undefined method `some_other_method'
```

Note that if you define `method_missing`, you should also define `respond_to_missing?` accordingly. Otherwise you get strange behavior like this:

```
x.respond_to?(:foo) # => false
x.foo               # Works. Huh?
```

In this particular case, we handle *all* messages, therefore we can simply define it as follows:

```
class X; def respond_to_missing?(*) true end end

x.respond_to?(:foo) # => true
```

Answer (score 5):

```
class X
  def method_missing(sym,*args)
    puts "Method #{sym} called with #{args}"
  end
end
a = X.new
a.blah("hello","world")

#=> Method blah called with ["hello", "world"]
```

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, you can define method_missing in ruby classes to handle this. Sorry that I can't provide specifics.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Test
  def say
     puts "hi"
  end
end
```

and you can invoke say method by

```
obj = Test.new
obj.send "say"
```

and checking the method availability using

```
obj.respond_to? "say"
```

finally, put together all

```
if (obj.respond_to? "say")
  obj.send "say"
end
```

Comment: -1 That's something completely unrelated. Read the question again.